# Spool Output using grep

Tags: grep

I have the following command to get SQL data from a fmb (Oracle Forms) file

```
strings test.fmb | egrep -i '(select|insert|update|delete)'
```

The output is spool in the window, how can I spool the output to a file?

Comment: using `> file` ?

Comment: @Archemar Thank you. If you can answer provide an answer, I will be glad to accept it.